# Excel design consideration - infrequent change and impact for VBA/formula/add-on

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

nothing stuck or broken, just I am inspired after a discussion with another Excel author.

His situation:

Read from an existing Excel monster file (column FG), and hard-coded the following

```
Range("FF:FG").Copy
```

Potential issue:
data in FF:FG will be pushed to GF:GG every couple of months because newer columns will be inserted in between. (It's a pivot-like design... sorry, but end-users need this appearance, but categories are increasing, summary need to be at right end side)

He has 2 other choices (if he don't want to maintain VBA code every few months):

***A:*** Store "FF","FG" in a Cell (fixed location!), then read the location parameter using VBA

***B:*** Read a second dedicated CSV file (copy/paste from the monster file, consumed by another user so available readily), it only has the 2 columns required..

To me, none is obviously better than the other, just a matter of preference.

***Similar but simpler Scene of mine***

I produce the monstrous file by lots of Vlookup from manual data sources (inherited the design... and I refactored the design using another automation tool but there is license consideration atm).

In a column there is a formula doing something like

```
=if(A1="SALES PERSON SICK","void result",(if(A1="MACHINE BROKEN",C2*0.8),"")..
```

say 5000 rows with this formula

To reduce hard-coding I moved
"SALES PERSON SICK","MACHINE BROKEN" to a reference sheet cell A1,A2, and changed formula to:

```
=if(A1=Ref!$A$1,"void result",(if(A1=Ref!$A$2,C2*0.8),"")
```

I feel it's a good practice.

Question: Is method A or B better? Considering column position will move every ~3-6 months, still worth choosing 1 from A/B?

Comment: If your colleague had to look at the sheet and find the new column position, how would they do it?  Automate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *data in FF:FG will be pushed to GF:GG every couple of months because newer columns will be inserted in between*

Then you should use named ranges in what you call *"monster file"* (see [Define and use names in formulas](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64)) and use them in your VBA.

Eg define a name for Columns FF:FG like `CopySource` (use a name that describes the data in that columns) and finally you can use that in your VBA code.

```
Range("CopySource").Copy
```

Whenever the range moves because new columns are inseted before, the named range moves too, so it still points to the same data.